# Creating a photo album viewer

Tags: c#, .net, photo, viewer

I want to create a form in C# which looks like the album viewer in iTunes.

I'm envisioning a grid which has lots of picture thumbnails, each with one or two lines of text underneath to display the name of the picture. And when I click on a picture thumbnail, I'd like to show a form with information about the picture.

Is there a control in C# which will let me do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) with enough finagling but it would not generate the thumbnails for you. You would have to do the thumbnails yourself. (You could also load the images into the grid control and let them be scaled but you would see serious performance issues with not too many images.)

Applications like the ones you describe are usually put together with 3rd party UI libraries like Telerik's grid (and many others) and 3rd party graphics packages. This is because though Microsoft provides some decent out-of-the-box controls to work with, fancier applications can get much more difficult to assemble from those controls.

If you don't want to or can't pay for 3rd party controls you can look into open source and demo projects like this one for [thumbnail generation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33929/Thumbnails-Generation) and [this as a grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3531/SourceGrid-Open-Source-C-Grid-Control).